# How to split a random image into 9 equal parts for puzzle game

Tags: c#

I am trying to split an image into 9 equal parts. Like we see in a puzzle game. Image can be any random image. I am trying some code but it is not splitting it into equal parts - it needs coordinate values for rectangles, but I need simple general code to split an image into equal parts.

I've an image. I want to crop it or split into 9 equal parts. But the below code just crops the same part of the image from the right top corner every time.

```
var imgarray = new Image[9];
var img = Image.FromFile("media\\a.png");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
var index = i * 3 + j;
        imgarray[index] = new Bitmap(104, 104);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[index]);
        graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, 104, 104), new Rectangle(i * 104, j * 104, 104, 104), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've formatted your code to make it easier to read. It's important - formatting your code is the first step towards writing bug-free code.

Comment: It appears that your `index` variable is never incremented and remains `0` throughout. All of your new `Bitmap` objects will (I assume) go into `imgarray[0]`. You need to increment `index` at the end of your inner loop.

Comment: I'm sorry I forget this line in code var index = i * 3 + j; it is right after inner loop. It increments the index. There is a problem the Rectangle method. It crops the same part of image every time. I want to crop an image of any size into equal parts

Comment: That seems important - please edit your question to add that line in where it appears in your code. Also, your question is unclear on what's actually failing. Please add some more detail about the result you expect when you're editing your question.

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: I would consider stretching/shrinking the image into a standard resolution.  Then just divide the Height/Width into 3rds--resulting in 9 segments.

Comment: I think size of the image is still a problem. I new code is close to solution but not exact. Can you please help me to make it more accurate?

Comment: It does the same that I posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

Some other tidy ups...

```
var imgarray = new Image[9];
var img = Image.FromFile("media\\a.png");
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
        imgarray[i] = new Bitmap(104, 104);
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[i]);
        graphics.DrawImage (
             img, 
             new Rectangle(0, 0, 104, 104),
             new Rectangle( (i%3) * 104, (i/3) * 104, 104, 104),
             GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        graphics.Dispose();
    }
}
```